# Off-delay timer with only a relay and an on-delay timer

Tags: relay, timer, delay

I'm trying to run two fans when there is a call for heat but I want fan 2 to shut off a few minutes later. I don't have an off delay timer however I do have an on-delay timer and a relay. I know it can work I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: (1) Mains? (2) Is the on-off switch a double-throw type (NO and NC contact)? (3) Is the timer NO, NC or changeover? Hit the [edit] link.

Comment: There's no need to edit the title after it's solved. Marking an answer as accepted marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fprV7S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Timing diagram and circuit schematic.*

How it works:

- TIMER1 is normally energised but when power is first switched on at the mains FAN2 will run until the timer times out.
- When SW1 is closed FAN1 will run, RLY1 will be energised and power off TIMER closing its NC contact causing FAN2 to run.
- When SW1 is opened FAN1 will switch off and RLY1 will drop out.
- TIMER will begin timing and when the set time has elapsed the TIMER contact will switch to the NO position switching off FAN2.

This pre-supposes that both the relay and timer have changeover contacts (but you gave no details or datasheet links).

Comment: Nope, This is exactly what I have! I apologize for the vagueness because I wasn't sure at first either.

Comment: Good. If it works then please accept the answer to indicate that it has been solved.

Comment: @Bigpaa: The "accept" button is located with the up/downvote buttons. When you accept the answer is marked in green on this page and the question is marked in green on the questions index. No need for "[solved]" in the title.